# It came in NDA 2018 and I want an explanation of the answer and do it fast

Tags: verb-agreement

The jury were/was called and their individual opinion were noted .what will come were or was

Comment: Pravesh, do you realise how rude and demanding this sounds? I'm strongly tempted not to respond. However ....

Answer (score -2):

> The jury was called, and the individual opinions of the members were
>   noted.

is the only way I'd write this.

Sometimes, notional concord ('The jury *were* called ...') sounds too non-idiomatic. 'The jury was called' is a fixed phrase, with the 'were' variant far less common.

Conflicts of agreement ('The jury *was* called and *their* individual opinions were noted.') should be avoided.

Comment: "the jury was polled"

Comment: @Greg Lee You're missed your calling.